# Связать линиями Button

Tags: java, android

Как провести линию от одной кнопки к другой в ScrollView?

Я рисовал так:

```
Bitmap bm = loadBitmapFromView( globalLayout );
Canvas canvas = new Canvas( bm );
....
canvas.drawLine( startx, starty, endx, endy, paint);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
globalLayout.setBackground( d );
```

Естественно, при скроллинге ScrollView, кнопки вместе с линиями между ними остаются на фоне.
Кроме как перерисовывать при скроллинге у меня идей нет.

Comment: Не должны оставаться, кнопки поместите в отд контейнер, чтоб на скролл не было реакции. Перерисовывать при скролле это в корне не правильный подход, я думаю вы сами понимаете, что рисовалки сильно грузят процесс. На самом деле, для того чтоб это сделать есть много вариантов, нужно понять как это выглядит и имеет ли смысл эта линия, для чего она нужна вообще.

Comment: Решил проблему , банальная невнимательность увы. Рисовалки грузят понимаю, но выхода не нашел другого, линии должны быть 100% ( визуальная связь между уровнями )

Answer (score 1):

Все дело было в банальной невнимательности.

Я менял background в глобальном лайауте в котором был ScrollView , а не в контейнере который внутри него.